# Can not see comments via Facebook on fr.sputniknews.com with Tor Browser 7.0.4. Why?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, noscript, facebook

All was fine with Tor Browser 7.0.2, I can see comments via Facebook on https://fr.sputniknews.com under all news. But it seems there's a bug now.  Do you have a solution ? If not, is it risky to still run Tor Browser 7.0.2 ?  Please avoid "Do not read Sputniknews anymore" comment ;-)

Comment: Not sure this is a Tor Browser bug and yes it is risky to run Tor Browser 7.0.2. When I view the facebook comments, I see it's using an `<iframe>` which is blank. Facebook is returning an empty page?

Comment: On the other hand...it may be relate to [this question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/15450/photos-broken-on-facebook).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have first disabled HTTPS Everywhere with no luck, then I have disabled NoScript and it worked, Facebook comments came back. Read Edit in my first post for more information.

Comment: Hi, could you maybe state your solutions as an answer to your own question instead of an edit to the question? It might help other users more.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a NoScript bug. When I disable 'Sanitize cross-site suspicious requests' in `NoScript Options\Advanced\XSS` then Facebook comments come back. So, it is the first solution to disable 'Sanitize...', but we are vulnerable to XSS attack if permanently disabled.

Second solution: tweak the NoScript `Options|Advanced|XSS|Anti-XSS Protection Exceptions` rules but I can not write such rule... not geek enough ;-). And last solution : post a [bug report at NoScript forum](https://forums.informaction.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=23168&p=89151). What I am going to do.